# Javascript count down to UTC 4am every day & every Sunday

Tags: javascript, countdown

I am building a resource for an MMORPG (game) that has daily and weekly resets. One reset is every Sunday @ 4am UTC and another is every day @ 4am UTC. I am looking to display countdown timers at the top of a page for these resets.

This Javascript code below counts down to midnight each day. How can I modify this code so I can build 2 countdowns. 1 that counts down to 4am UTC (daily) and another that counts down to 4am UTC every Sunday?

```js
var div = document.getElementById("bb");

setInterval(function() { 
    var toDate = new Date();
    var tomorrow = new Date();
    tomorrow.setHours(24, 0, 0, 0);
    var diffMS = tomorrow.getTime() / 1000 - toDate.getTime() / 1000;
    var diffHr = Math.floor(diffMS / 3600);
    diffMS = diffMS - diffHr * 3600;
    var diffMi = Math.floor(diffMS / 60);
    diffMS = diffMS - diffMi * 60;
    var diffS = Math.floor(diffMS);
    var result = ((diffHr < 10) ? "0" + diffHr : diffHr);
    result += ":" + ((diffMi < 10) ? "0" + diffMi : diffMi);
    result += ":" + ((diffS < 10) ? "0" + diffS : diffS);
    div.innerHTML = result;
},1000);
```

```html
<div id="bb">
</div>
```

Comment: Your interval isn't going to run if the user leaves the page...or even focuses a different time depending on the browser. Are you expecting players to have the page up and focused 24/7? If you have a web client you will have to do work like this on the server.

Comment: Hey @JaredSmith - the resource I was talking about is a web page; it's a game guide essentially. It will display when the resets happen in game. So yes, the JS will only run when the web page is opened. To paraphrase the question: Is there a way to get the countdown clock to use UTC (Universal time zone) instead of the user's computer clock and then count down to 4AM?

Answer (score 1):

I've written this code below using what you had already:

```js
var div = document.getElementById("bb");
var div2 = document.getElementById("bc");

setInterval(function() { 
    var toDate = new Date();
    var timezoneOffset =  toDate.getTimezoneOffset() / 60; // difference in hours from GMT
    
    var tomorrow = new Date();
    tomorrow.setHours(28, 0, 0);
    var diffMS = tomorrow.getTime() / 1000 - toDate.getTime() / 1000;
    var diffHr = Math.floor(diffMS / 3600);
    diffMS = diffMS - diffHr * 3600;
    var diffMi = Math.floor(diffMS / 60);
    diffMS = diffMS - diffMi * 60;
    var diffS = Math.floor(diffMS);
    diffHr -= timezoneOffset;
    var result = ((diffHr < 10) ? "0" + diffHr : diffHr);
    result += ":" + ((diffMi < 10) ? "0" + diffMi : diffMi);
    result += ":" + ((diffS < 10) ? "0" + diffS : diffS);
    div.innerHTML = result;
    
    var nextSunday = getNextSunday(new Date());
    nextSunday.setHours(4, 0, 0);
    diffMS = nextSunday.getTime() / 1000 - toDate.getTime() / 1000;
    diffHr = Math.floor(diffMS / 3600);
    diffMS = diffMS - diffHr * 3600;
    diffMi = Math.floor(diffMS / 60);
    diffMS = diffMS - diffMi * 60;
    diffS = Math.floor(diffMS);
    diffHr -= timezoneOffset;
    result = ((diffHr < 10) ? "0" + diffHr : diffHr);
    result += ":" + ((diffMi < 10) ? "0" + diffMi : diffMi);
    result += ":" + ((diffS < 10) ? "0" + diffS : diffS);
    div2.innerHTML = result;
}, 1000);

function getNextSunday(d) {
  var t = new Date(d);
  t.setDate(d.getDate() + (7 - d.getDay()) % 7);
  return t;
}
```

```html
<div id="bb">
</div>
<div id="bc">
</div>
```

Firstly, I made a small change to add 4 hours to `tomorrow` so that it's set for 4 am, instead of midnight.

Afterwards, I just added another `div` where I can put the time between now and Sunday at 4 am and a function to get the date for the next Sunday at the bottom.

I added an offset for the UTC conversion which is applied at the end. After that, the code is almost identical to what you had already written!

Comment: Firstly, thank you - makes total sense seeing it written out now. Secondly, the main problem was setting the tone to UTC (Coordinated Universal Time). The game's servers are set to UTC. Is there a way to do that via Javascript?

Comment: @DoMx I've just updated my code to account for the UTC timezone, let me know if it works!

Comment: That works for me, as I'm in the UK, but if somebody from say Los Angeles or Mexico views the page it will offset their local time by 60 minutes and won't show UTC? Found a bit of lead through Googling but is there a way to pull UTC using something like .getUTCTime then using your code to countdown to 4am (daily) and 4am Sunday?

Comment: Nope, I'm from Canada, and when I run the code it counts down to UTC 4 am as well on both the daily and the weekly timer!

Answer (score 0):

Try this code:

```js
var dailyResetDiv = document.getElementById("dailyReset");
var weeklyResetDiv = document.getElementById("weeklyReset");

function updateCountdown(targetDate, outputElement) {
    var now = new Date();
    var diffMS = targetDate.getTime() - now.getTime();
    var diffHr = Math.floor(diffMS / 3600000);
    diffMS = diffMS - diffHr * 3600000;
    var diffMi = Math.floor(diffMS / 60000);
    diffMS = diffMS - diffMi * 60000;
    var diffS = Math.floor(diffMS / 1000);
    var result =
        (diffHr < 10 ? "0" + diffHr : diffHr) +
        ":" +
        (diffMi < 10 ? "0" + diffMi : diffMi) +
        ":" +
        (diffS < 10 ? "0" + diffS : diffS);
    outputElement.innerHTML = result;
}

setInterval(function () {
    // Daily reset at 4am UTC
    var dailyReset = new Date();
    dailyReset.setUTCHours(4, 0, 0, 0);
    updateCountdown(dailyReset, dailyResetDiv);

    // Weekly reset on Sunday at 4am UTC
    var weeklyReset = new Date();
    weeklyReset.setUTCHours(4, 0, 0, 0);
    var dayOfWeek = weeklyReset.getUTCDay();
    if (dayOfWeek !== 0) {
        // If not Sunday, adjust the date to the next Sunday
        weeklyReset.setUTCDate(weeklyReset.getUTCDate() + (7 - dayOfWeek));
    }
    updateCountdown(weeklyReset, weeklyResetDiv);
}, 1000);
```

```html
<div id="dailyReset"></div>
<div id="weeklyReset"></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You could try an OOP approach by creating a timer class. You would only need to compute the target date once. The timer will call the render function on an interval.

```js
const localTimeEl = document.querySelector('#local-time');
const utcTimeEl = document.querySelector('#utc-time');
const timerEl1 = document.querySelector('#timer-1');
const timerEl2 = document.querySelector('#timer-2');
const timerEl3 = document.querySelector('#timer-3');

const main = () => {
  // Local Time
  looper(() => { localTimeEl.textContent = getLocaleTimeString(); }, 1000);

  // UTC Time
  looper(() => { utcTimeEl.textContent = getLocaleTimeString('UTC'); }, 1000);
  
  // Every day
  const timer1 = new CountdownTimer({
    time: '04:00',
    timeZone: 'UTC',
    renderFn: (duration) => {
      timerEl1.textContent = formatDuration(duration);
    }
  }).start();

  // Next Sunday
  const timer2 = new CountdownTimer({
    time: '04:00',
    timeZone: 'UTC',
    dayOfWeek: 0,
    renderFn: (duration) => {
      timerEl2.textContent = formatDuration(duration);
    }
  }).start();
  
  // Today
  const timer3 = new CountdownTimer({
    time: '12:00',
    timeZone: 'PDT',
    isToday: true,
    renderFn: (duration) => {
      timerEl3.textContent = formatDuration(duration);
    }
  }).start();
};

const looper = (callback, ms) => {
  setInterval(callback, ms);
  callback();
};

const getLocaleTimeString = (timeZone) =>
  new Date().toLocaleString('en-US', { timeZone });

const parseDuration = (duration) => {
  duration = +duration;
  const days = Math.floor(duration / 8.64e7);
  duration %= 8.64e7;
  const hours = Math.floor(duration / 3.6e6);
  duration %= 3.6e6;;
  const minutes = Math.floor(duration / 6e4);
  duration %= 6e4;
  const seconds = Math.floor(duration / 1e3);
  return { days, hours, minutes, seconds };
}

const applyUnit = (value, singular, plural) =>
  value > 0
    ? value + (value === 1 ? ` ${singular}` : ` ${plural}`)
    : null;

const formatDurationFull = (duration) => {
  const { days, hours, minutes, seconds } = parseDuration(duration);
  return [
    applyUnit(days, 'day', 'days'),
    applyUnit(hours, 'hour', 'hours'),
    applyUnit(minutes, 'minute', 'minutes'),
    applyUnit(seconds, 'second', 'seconds'),
  ].filter(v => v).join(', ');
};

const formatDurationSimple = (duration) => {
  const { days, hours, minutes, seconds } = parseDuration(duration);
  return [ days, hours, minutes, seconds ]
    .map(v => v.toString().padStart(2, '0')).join(':');
};

const formatDuration = (duration) =>
  duration > 0
  ? `${formatDurationSimple(duration)} (${formatDurationFull(duration)})`
  : 'Expired';

const getDateNextWeek = (date, dayOfWeek = 0) => {
  const currentDate = new Date(date);
  currentDate.setDate(currentDate.getDate() + (7 - currentDate.getDay() + dayOfWeek) % 7);
  return currentDate;
};

const getTomorrow = (date) => {
  const currentDate = new Date(date);
  currentDate.setDate(currentDate.getDate() + 1);
  return currentDate;
};

class CountdownTimer {
  constructor(options) {
    const opts = { ...options };
    this.time = opts.time;
    this.timeZone = opts.timeZone;
    this.dayOfWeek = opts.dayOfWeek;
    this.renderFn = opts.renderFn;
    this.isToday = opts.isToday ?? false;
    this.targetDate = this.computeTargetDate();
  }
  start() {
    this.stop();
    this.update();
    this.intervalId = setInterval(this.update.bind(this), 1000);
    return this;
  }
  stop() {
    if (this.intervalId) {
      clearInterval(this.intervalId);
    }
    this.intervalId = undefined;
    return this;
  }
  update() {
    this.renderFn(this.targetDate - new Date());
  }
  // 2019-01-01T00:00:00.000+00:00
  computeTargetDate() {
    const now = new Date();
    const timeTokens = this.time.split(':').map(value => +value);
    const futureHour = timeTokens[0] ?? 0;
    const futureMinute = timeTokens[1] ?? 0;
    const futureSecond = timeTokens[2] ?? 0;
    const timeZone = this.parseTimeZone(this.timeZone);
    let targetDate;
    if (this.isToday) {
      targetDate = now;
    } else {
      if (this.dayOfWeek === undefined) {
        targetDate = getTomorrow(now);
      } else {
        targetDate = getDateNextWeek(now, this.dayOfWeek);
      }
    }
    const y = targetDate.getUTCFullYear();
    const m = (targetDate.getUTCMonth() + 1).toString().padStart(2, '0');
    const d = targetDate.getUTCDate().toString().padStart(2, '0');
    const H = futureHour.toString().padStart(2, '0');
    const M = futureMinute.toString().padStart(2, '0');
    const s = futureSecond.toString().padStart(2, '0');
    const ts = `${y}-${m}-${d}T${H}:${M}:${s}${timeZone}`;
    console.log(`Countdown target date: ${ts}`);
    return Date.parse(ts);
  }
  parseTimeZone(timeZone) {
    const offsetMinutes = this.timeZoneToMinutes(timeZone);
    if (offsetMinutes == null) return '';
    const sign = offsetMinutes < 0 ? '-' : '+';
    const h = Math.abs(offsetMinutes / 60).toString().padStart(2, '0');
    const m = Math.abs(offsetMinutes % 60).toString().padStart(2, '0');
    return `${sign}${h}${m}`;
  }
  timeZoneToMinutes(timeZone) {
    switch (timeZone) {
      case 'UTC':
      case 'GMT':
        return 0;
      case 'EDT': return -240;
      case 'EST': return -300;
      case 'CDT': return -300;
      case 'CST': return -360;
      case 'MDT': return -360;
      case 'MST': return -420;
      case 'PDT': return -420;
      case 'PST': return -480;
      default:
        return null;
    }
  }
}

main();
```

```css
h2 { margin: 0; padding: 0; margin-top: 0.25rem; font-size: 1.25rem; }
.grid { display: grid; grid-template-rows: repeat(2, auto); grid-auto-flow: column; }
```

```html
<div class="grid">
  <h2>Local Time</h2>
  <div id="local-time"></div>
  <h2>UTC Time</h2>
  <div id="utc-time"></div>
</div>
<h2>Tomorrow @ 4am UTC</h2>
<div id="timer-1"></div>
<h2>Sunday @ 4am UTC</h2>
<div id="timer-2"></div>
<h2>Today @ 12pm PDT (-07:00)</h2>
<div id="timer-3"></div>
```